# c# combobox выборка по ID

Tags: c#

есть 2 combobox-a первый выводит данные с помощью SELECT (id, name), второй combobox должен вывести  совпадающие с первым комбобоксом записи. ниже выложил код, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
  void SelectCombobox1()
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT sum.id, sum.name FROM sum", con);
        DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
        adapterr.Fill(dsett);
        for (int i = 0; i < dsett.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            combobox1.Items.Add(dsett.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + " | " + dsett.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
        }
    }



void SelectCombobox2()
    {
       
        MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT dslam.id, dslam.ip FROM dslam JOIN sum ON dslam.sats_id = sum.id WHERE dslam.sats_id = '"+combobox1.Text.ToString()+"'", con);

        DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
        adapterr.Fill(dsett);
        for (int i = 0; i < dsett.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           
            Combobox2.Items.Add(dsett.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + " | " + dsett.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
        }
       
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем проблема отсортировать прямо в SQL? `SELECT sum.id, sum.name FROM sum ORDER BY sum.id ASC`

Comment: там WHERE не работает , я хочу фильтровать по Combobox-у.  тоесть выбираю один ID из первого комбобокса , во втором должен выводится запись этого ID

Comment: И что же по-вашему содержит `combobox1.Text`? Отладка, точка останова, не?

Comment: вот добавил изображение ,  вывод комбобоксов из БД , первый комбобокс выводит ID и Name,  второй комбобокс привязан другой таблице БД, но они между собой связанный через ID.  тут как видно  второй комбобокс выводит все значения. я хочу фильтровать  по ID первого комбобокса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно вы комбобоксы наполняете. База вообще штука умная, можно результаты оттуда в нужном виде сразу забирать.

```
void SelectCombobox1()
{
    using MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT sum.id AS id, CONCAT(sum.id, '|', sum.name) as name FROM sum", con);
    DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
    adapterr.Fill(dsett);
    combobox1.ValueMember = "id";
    combobox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    combobox1.DataSource = dsett.Tables[0];
}

void SelectCombobox2()
{
    using MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT dslam.id AS id, CONCAT(dslam.id, '|', dslam.ip) AS ip FROM dslam JOIN sum ON dslam.sats_id = sum.id WHERE dslam.sats_id = " + combobox1.SelectedValue, con);
    DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
    adapterr.Fill(dsett);
    Combobox2.ValueMember = "id";
    Combobox2.DisplayMember = "ip";
    Combobox2.DataSource = dsett.Tables[0];
}
```

> при запуске формы combobox автоматом выбирает первый элемент , и во втором комбобоксе выборка только по первого элемента первого комбобокса

```
void SelectCombobox1()
{
    using MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT sum.id AS id, CONCAT(sum.id, '|', sum.name) as name FROM sum", con);
    DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
    adapterr.Fill(dsett);
    combobox1.ValueMember = "id";
    combobox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    DataTable dt = dsett.Tables[0];
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["id"] = -1;
    dr["name"] = "All";
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    combobox1.DataSource = dt;
}

void SelectCombobox2()
{
    using MySqlDataAdapter adapterr = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT dslam.id AS id, CONCAT(dslam.id, '|', dslam.ip) AS ip FROM dslam JOIN sum ON dslam.sats_id = sum.id" + ((int)combobox1.SelectedValue == -1 ? "" : " WHERE dslam.sats_id = " + combobox1.SelectedValue), con);
    DataSet dsett = new DataSet();
    adapterr.Fill(dsett);
    Combobox2.ValueMember = "id";
    Combobox2.DisplayMember = "ip";
    Combobox2.DataSource = dsett.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: блин, отлично работает ! спасибо ! а можно такой нюанс уточнить , при запуске формы combobox автоматом выбирает первый элемент ,  и во втором комбобоксе выборка только по первого элемента первого комбобокса,  `combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;` не работает

Comment: @Misterjunior дополнил ответ, это должно было быть просто.

Comment: второй код почему то не производит выборку ...

Comment: @Misterjunior отлаживайте код, убедитесь что верно скопировали, я кое-что подправил после публикации.

Answer (score 0):

Короче то, что тебе нужно называется не сортировка, а выборка)

Во-первых убедись, что Text даёт то, что тебе нужно

Скорее всего там должно быть что-то типу

```
var id = (MyClass)combobox.SelectedItem
```

ну это, концептуально. А так-то посмотри в сторону https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

и продебаж, убедись что в СКЛ попадает именно то, что тебе надо

Comment: я хотел сравнить со значением первого комбобокса и вывести во второй комбобокс соответствующую запись

Comment: тоесть в первом комбобоксе есть 15 ID ,   пользователь выбирал второй ID - второй комбобокс отсортировал и вывел все значение имеющие отношение к второму ID

Comment: По-моему текст проперти тут не применим
попробуй SelectedItem
и продебаж, убедись, что ты получаешь именно тот ID и его ToString метод даёт нужный результат

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: и да, ты неправильный вопрос задал. 

не сортировка, а выборка)

Comment: упс , сорри , да выборка ! запутался я )

Comment: там второй комбобокс выводит все значение , а их штук 200 , а я хочу выбирать  записи  в зависимости от первого комбобокса , и я подумал может проблема самой условии WHERE